# Easy Form validation library for PHP?

Tags: php, validation

I need a simple php library which can be used to easily pass rules and field names to, and then validation could be easily performed. There should also be an easy way to retrieve the errors.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

> Update (January 2024): The question has been closed. The libraries recommended in this answer, written about four years ago, are no longer maintained.

Answering because I had the exact same question, and had to test out a few libraries to get an answer.
Here are some options:

1. [rakit/validation](https://github.com/rakit/validation).

> PHP Standalone library for validating data. Inspired by Illuminate\Validation Laravel.

The syntax is familiar if you have worked with Laravel before.

2. [vlucas/valitron](https://github.com/vlucas/valitron).

> Simple, minimal and elegant stand-alone validation library with NO dependencies.

The syntax seems to be more concise and straightforward.

Also check out [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/bpv47g/recommend_php_libary_for_validation/) thread on r/PHP.